# Facing url redirection issue on html site

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html website, want to redirect the mbcv.com to mbcv.com/index.html, so when anyone type mbcv.com it willl re-direct to the mbcv.com/index.html
i added js code but when the page is loading it is loading, refreshing for infinity time not stopped.
these code is not working for me

```
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL="/index.html" />

 <script type="text/javascript>">
 window.location = "/index.html";
 </script>
```

Comment: web server takes index.html as default file to serve at `/`, so when you are pointing your location to either `/` or `/index.html` it will point to the same code which refreshes for ever. so redirecting from `/` to `/index.html` no difference

Answer (score 1):

maybe can help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript>">
   if (window.location.pathname === "/") {
       window.location = "/index.html";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.location.pathname == "/") {
   window.location.href = "/index.html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making an index.js file and then linking that to html file, because the problem is probably your trying to link to another site in the same file as the site your html site.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
it will redirect when loaded

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {window.location.replace("Your");});
```